# Trying to Output Windows Environment Variables in a Simple CMD I'm Working on (Batch)

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to output Windows Environment Variables in a simple CMD shell I'm currently working on. It's code is short and simple:

```
@echo off

cd %userprofile%

:begin

echo.

set cmd=
set /p cmd=%cd%^>

%cmd%

goto :begin
```

The purpose of this is to provide an "alternative" command prompt when the actual command prompt is disabled. All it does is takes the user's input as a command and outputs it. However, when attempting to output environment variables, it will output the raw variable name you put into it. Example, when I input "echo %time%" it will output "%time%" as opposed to something like "12:05:33.39". Is there any way I can implement some code that will allow for the output of environment variables? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
cd %userprofile%
:begin
echo.
set cmd=
set /p cmd=%cd%^>^>
call %cmd%
goto :begin
```

You can take a look at the `prompt` command too `prompt /?`

example :

`prompt $p-$t^>`

Comment: This solves it. I can't thank you enough, nor can I vote up your answer due to my low reputation :( Let it be known you have saved me a lot of time and headaches, as I could not for the life of me figure out how to fix this. One simple command has put all to rest. Thank you so much.